# Shopware update captcha not visible

Tags: javascript, modernizr, shopware

I have updated Shopware from **5.2.2(5|6)**[Rev. 201706221543] to **5.4.6**  *(Rev. 201807181357)*.

The form contains captcha. But after an update I have to click on a field to see it. Why?

When I click any field computed and cached Modernizr js file executes:

```
widgets/Captcha/refreshCaptcha?_=15...
```

so captcha reloads and appears.

---

**Modernizr:**

```
n.ajaxTransport(function(b) {
...
  try {
    h.send(b.hasContent && b.data || null) <-- Console shows that string
```

**HTML before:**

```
<div class="captcha--placeholder" data-src="/widgets/Captcha/refreshCaptcha"></div>
```

**HTML after clicking any input field:**

```
<div class="captcha--placeholder" data-src="/widgets/Captcha/refreshCaptcha">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iV...=" alt="Captcha">
  <input type="hidden" name="sRand" value="fj..">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of shopware. The reason for this might be, that the captcha will only be loaded, when it is needed. There is a captcha on the detail-page as well and in shopware versions < 5.3 on every detail request a captcha was loaded, causing a slower site performance. Now the captcha is only loaded when accessing the rating tab. So the main reason is minimizing requests.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: You can change the template files to auto-load the captcha. The jQuery plugin has an option "autoLoad":  https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.4/themes/Frontend/Responsive/frontend/_public/src/js/jquery.captcha.js#L31

By adding data-autoLoad="true" to the capcha-div you can load instantly. E.g. for the detailpage you need to add it to this line https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.4/themes/Frontend/Bare/frontend/detail/comment/form.tpl#L82